# I am getting the following exceptions I tried placing quotes and commas between the values still I am not able to resolve

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
>   to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1,2,3,4) 
>   values ('2017-01-11','P','P','P','A')' at line 1

The error is possibly in the `insertColumn` and `insertValue` variable. I am not able to get the syntax right. Possibly I may be missing some quotes in the variables, but I don't know where. I referred to different sources online but the attempts failed. `columnNames` is a list that has all the columns.

```
 String insertColumns = ""; 
 String insertValues = "";

 if(columnNames != null && columnNames.size() > 0){
    insertColumns +=  columnNames.get(0);
    insertValues += "?";
 }


 for(int i = 1; i < columnNames.size();i++){
  insertColumns += "," + columnNames.get(i) ;
  insertValues += ","+"?";
 }
 System.out.println(insertColumns);
 String insertSql; 
 //Here is where the problem lies
 insertSql = "INSERT INTO os ("+ insertColumns+") values (" + insertValues + 
 ")";
 System.out.println(insertSql);        
 try{
 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql);
 ps.setDate(1, sqlStartDate);
 for(int i=1;i<=no_of_stud;i++){
    int j=i+1;
    int k=i-1;
    ps.setString(j, present[k]);
 }
```

Comment: What's the output from `System.out.println(insertSql);` ?

Comment: You can eliminate a lot of ambiguity by using `String insertColumns = String.join(",", columnNames);` and `String insertValues = String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(columnNames.size(), "?"));`.

Comment: Try to edit : `insertColumns +=  columnNames.get(0);` To `insertColumns += "'"+ columnNames.get(0) +"'";` and `insertColumns += "," + columnNames.get(i) ;` to `insertColumns += "," + "'"+ columnNames.get(i)  +"'";

Comment: Please edit your question to post a title that accurately represents/summarizes your question.

Comment: The column names are just "1" up to "4"? That are no column names; you could use `stud1` ... `stud4`. And the start date column is missing.

Comment: Debugging 101: What does System.out.println(insertSql); show you?

Comment: INSERT INTO os (Date,1,2,3,4) values (?,?,?,?,?)    @SamM this is the output the println(insertsql) shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/identifier-names/

> Identifier names may begin with a numeral, but can't only contain numerals unless quoted.

so instead of: `insertColumns +=  columnNames.get(i);` you should have:

This worked.

> insertColumns +=  "`" + columnNames.get(i) + "`" ;

also the first if should test the something else. For example:

```
if(columnNames == null || columnNames.size() <= 0){
  return;
}
```